# Jasmine: Is there a way to mock a locally used service?

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, mocking, jasmine

I am fairly new to Angular and Jasmine testing, so I am trying to check if this method works correctly, but I need to mock `XmlReaderService`, it is used only locally, how could I mock this? I would expect something with `spyOn` but cannot get my head around it...

```
  private getElementSettings() {
    const xmlReader = new XmlReaderService(this.logger)
    xmlReader.requestXml(this.xmlServiceUrl + this.settingsFileName).then(() => {
      this.elementSettings = xmlReader.xmlJsoned['element_settings']
      this.getElementTypes()
      this.getElementList()
      this.getMonitors()
    }).catch((reason) => {
      this.logger.error('XML Request failed in getElementSettings()!')
      this.logger.info(reason, '[' + this.constructor.name + ']')
      this.delegate.errorCallback(650, 'XML Request failed - could not get smart home element definitions (ElementSettings.xml)', reason)
    })
  }
```

Comment: Mocking it like how you have it will be difficult. If you inject the service in the constructor, it will be easier to test. Read Component with a dependency here: (https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios).

Comment: Hi @AliF50 thanks! I ended up refactoring it to improve testability...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comment from @AliF50 above. It´s not really well testable this way...